# Saving incoming emails as files, then reading them, (android and javamail)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am working on a android project that can read e-mails from any gmail account, what i wanted to do is receiving read or unread mails from Inbox, and then store them as files. My purpose is getting all mails and then reading them without any internet connection. I'm using javamail for android for sending emails. What do you offer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against storing them simply as files.  That is very insecure and results in the device being easily compromised.  That is why you hear so much on the news about "thousands of emails stolen from government employee's laptop, blah blah".

I would advise you to use AppData to store this information.  This way, it's locally stored, but is a bit more secure than a raw text file.  You may even want to encrypt the AppData using a username and password.

Hope this helps!